# How to pass initial state to reducer

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql

I currently create my store with one reducer which has the initial state passed to it.

```
import reducers from './reducers'

const store = createStore(
    reducers,
    initialState,
    compose(...enhancers)
  )


// reducers.js
export default function reducer(state, action) {
  console.log('state', state)
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'LOAD_UI':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loadUI: action.loaded
      });
    case 'NO_MATCH':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loadUI: true,
        isNoMatch: action.isNoMatch
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

When I log state with in my reducer function, I get the state that is set when I configure my store:

```
// if we are in production mode, we get the initial state from the window object, otherwise, when we are in dev env we get it from a static file
const preloadedState = window.__INITIAL_STATE__ === '{{__PRELOADEDSTATE__}}' ? initialState : window.__INITIAL_STATE__

const store = configureStore(preloadedState)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Now I want to use another reducer as I am trying to include Apollo in my project. According to http://dev.apollodata.com/react/redux.html I need to combineReducers: i.e.

```
combineReducers({
    todos: todoReducer,
    users: userReducer,
    apollo: client.reducer(),
  }),
```

So I would need to do somthing like this:

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      apollo: client.reducer(),
      reducer: reducers
    }),
    initialState,
    compose(...enhancers)
  )
```

But then my reducer function no longer has access to state (it is undefined). How can I ensure this gets passed through when I use combineReducers?

**Solution:**

As per Daniel Rearden suggestion, I needed to match my reducers' keys to that of my initial state.

My initialState looks something like:

```
{
  "pages": [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "title": "About",
      "slug": "about",
      "path": "/about",
      "template": "about",
      "published": "2017-07-10 02:02:30",
      "image": null,
      "seo": {
        "title": null,
        "description": null,
        "image": null,
        "fbAdmins": null,
        "gtm": null,
        "schema": ""
      },
      "sections": [
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 10,
      "title": "Contact",
      "slug": "contact",
      "path": "/contact",
      "template": "contact",
      "published": "2017-07-11 04:27:30",
      "image": null,
      "seo": {
        "title": null,
        "description": null,
        "image": null,
        "fbAdmins": null,
        "gtm": null,
        "schema": ""
      },
      "sections": []
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "title": "Home",
      "slug": "home",
      "path": "/",
      "template": "home",
      "published": "2017-07-10 01:39:48",
      "image": null,
      "seo": {
        "title": null,
        "description": null,
        "image": null,
        "fbAdmins": null,
        "gtm": null,
        "schema": ""
      },
      "sections": []
    }
  ],
  "services": [],
  "clients": [],
  "people": [],
  "offices": [],
  "articles": [],
  "menus": {
    "header": [
      {
        "title": "Home",
        "slug": "/"
      },
      {
        "title": "About",
        "slug": "/about"
      },
      {
        "title": "Contact",
        "slug": "/contact"
      }
    ]
  },
  "settings": {
    "site": {
      "title": null,
      "siteUrl": ""
    },
    "logo": [],
    "secondarylogo": [],
    "favicon": [],
    "disclaimer": null,
    "tagline": null,
    "social": null,
    "email": null,
    "phone": null,
    "facebookAppId": "",
    "seo": {
      "title": null,
      "description": null,
      "image": null,
      "fbAdmins": null,
      "gtm": null,
      "schema": ""
    },
    "newsLetterSignUp": {
      "image": "",
      "title": "",
      "content": ""
    },
    "menu_settings": null
  }
}
```

So my reducer looks something like this:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { ApolloClient } from 'react-apollo';

const client = new ApolloClient();

import articles from './articles'
import pages from './pages'
import services from './services'
import clients from './clients'
import people from './people'
import offices from './offices'
import menus from './menus'
import settings from './settings'

export default combineReducers({
  apollo: client.reducer(),
  articles,
  pages,
  services,
  clients,
  people,
  offices,
  menus,
  settings
})
```

So that my `pages` reducer only gets the pages slice of my initialState.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason this isn't working as you'd expect is because you've altered the structure of your state, as well as what gets passed to your original reducers. Where before your store looked something like this:

```
{
 loadUI: true
 isNoMatch: false
}
```

Now, you've basically told Redux to look for:

```
{
 apollo: {
   // ✁
 }
 reducers: {
   loadUI: true
   isNoMatch: false
 }
}
```

When you use combineReducers, you are essentially creating isolated domains for your state -- instead of passing in the entire state to each reducer, redux will only pass in a slice of the state to each reducer and that reducer will only be able to alter that slice of state. By structuring your store as shown above, you've told redux to pass only the `apollo` slice of the state to the apollo reducer... and the `reducers` part of the state to your original reducers.

I'm guessing you haven't made any changes to `preloadedState`. So what's happening is redux is looking for a property in `preloadedState` called `reducers` and passing that to your reducers. It can't find one, so it passes in undefined.

The easiest fix here is, first, pick something more descriptive than `reducers` -- `ui` maybe? Change your combineReducers accordingly. Then update your `preloadedState` so that whatever intial state you had is nested inside `ui`. Then it should work as expected. Just keep in mind you'll need to update your selectors and/or mapStateToProps functions too!

**Edit:** You may want to read up more about how combineReducers works [here](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/UsingCombineReducers.html).

Comment: Thanks. That was worth reading how `combineReducers` works. I was missing the fact that each reducer gets mapped to a key within the preloaded state.